# How to make a programmatically push to a uicollectionview with custom cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have two views in my app, the main view controller (`viewcontroller.m`) and a UICollectionView (`photoListViewController.m`), and something strange is happening, If a create a button on the main view controller, and create a PUSH via Storyboard, everything work's fine, but when i try to create the push programmatically i'm getting the following error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UICollectionView.m:3241

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

I have created a custom class (photoListCell) to the cells, and connected everything via storyboard.

```
photoListCell.h 

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *cellBackgroundImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellDataLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellNameLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *cellFooterImage;
```

This is how i'm creating the push on the Viewcontroller.m

```
-(void)goToPhotoList: {
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *cvLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
        [cvLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
        [cvLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(105, 105)];
        PhotoListViewController *photoVC = [[PhotoListViewController alloc]initWithCollectionViewLayout:cvLayout];

        photoVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext; // Pass core data context

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:photoVC animated:NO]; }
```

And here is how i'm creating the cells in the collection view photoListViewController.m

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    photoListCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.cellBackgroundImage.image = [UIimage imageNamed:@"Something"];
cell.cellFooterImage.alpha = 0.5;
cell.cellDataLabel.text = @"Something";

return cell; }
```

What should i do? Any help will be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your collection view cell is created in the storyboard, and has the identifier "Cell", then your problem is that you're not getting the instance of the PhotoListViewController from the storyboard by using this line,

```
PhotoListViewController *photoVC = [[PhotoListViewController alloc]initWithCollectionViewLayout:cvLayout];
```

Instead, you should give your storyboard controller an identifier (I'll call it "PhotoListVC" for my example), and instantiate it like this,

```
PhotoListViewController *photoVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PhotoListVC"];
```

Comment: Nailed it! Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you! can someone give a swift 4 version of this line, please?

Answer (score 0):

my guess is your collection view controller in the storyboard includes a cell prototype linked to the reuse identifier "Cell". when you instantiate the view yourself (not from the storyboard), you are missing the definition of this cell class.

here is what you should do:

1. have your collection view cell class defined in its own nib (nog in the storyboard)
2. register this nib and map it to the identifier "Cell" in the collection view controller - something like this:

   UINib* nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"DatePickerTableViewCell" bundle:nil];
   [self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];